# Batch look ahead? variables

Tags: batch-file, variables, regex-lookarounds

How to achieve this?

```
set newline=^& echo. 
set header=my header^%newline% %abc%^%newline%%def%^%newline%end
```

...

```
set abc=some text 
set def=some more text 
echo %header%
```

...

```
set abc=hello
set def=there
echo %header%
```

Expected output:

```
my header
some text
some more text
end
my header
hello
there
end
```

Output now: (abc and def values are not displayed)

```
my header


end
my header


end
```

Thanks in advance! Appreciate any solution.

Update:
I am writing a script that summarizes the execution result and displaying this at the first lines of output, e.g.

```
c:\> myScript.bat
----------------------------------------
Execution failed with cmd1=UP, cmd2=DOWN
cmd2 failed
----------------------------------------

COMMAND: cmd1
[output of cmd1]

cmd1 result is "UP"

COMMAND: cmd2
[outout of cmd2]

cmd2 result is "DOWN"
```

Comment: As far as I know, this can't be achieved.

Comment: Is it the `newline` you're having a problem with (which might be addressed by [npocmaka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46789104/2096401)), or to be able to alter what gets substituted into `header` on the fly? (**Tip**: show what you get / describe how it's wrong _as well as_ showing what you want/expect). If it is the latter, I suspect you'll have to put the `set header=...` (and possibly an `echo %header%`) inside a `call :doheader` function to be called whenever `abc` or `def` changes.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
REM Creating a Newline variable (the two blank lines are required!)
set NLM=^


set NL=^^^%NLM%%NLM%^%NLM%%NLM%
:::::
set header=my header%NL% %abc%%NL%%def%%NL%end
```

try this.

Or

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(set \n=^
%=Do not remove this line=%
)

 set header=my header!\n! %abc%!\n!%def%!\n!end
```